# Count instances of same item within range

Tags: excel-formula

Setup in Excel:
Two columns, an identifiaction and a timestamp.

What I'm trying to achieve is a count of every time the same ID has a timestamp of less than one minute apart. So when the same ID has two or more entries within one minute of eachother it should be counted as 1 instance, if the ID+timestamp is unique it should not be counted.

Example:

```
ID      time
1111    2014/06/18 14:03
1111    2014/06/18 15:12
1112    2014/06/18 15:03
1112    2014/06/18 15:04
1112    2014/06/18 18:03
1112    2014/06/18 18:03
1113    2014/06/18 14:02
1113    2014/06/18 14:03
1113    2014/06/18 14:03
```

This should result in "3" twice for 1112 (once at 15:03 and once at 18:03) and once for 1113.

I've tried all kinds of =COUNTIF, =DCOUNT, etc combinations. but I keep getting hung up at the once minute issue and the more than two still only equals one count.

Hope someone can help with a (probably simple) solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) order the data, first criteria by ID; second criteria by time

2) In a new column starting in the second row:
=if( AND(upper_cell.id=this_row.id;abs(upper_cell.time - this_row.time)<=(1/(24*60))) ; 1 ; 0)

3) add the values of the new column

Comment: That doesn't work. Shure it outputs the correct number in the end but it does so wrongly. It doesn't count the one minute difference of 1112 shanging 1/24*60 to 0,000694 makes it work though. But it also counts 1113 twice. Sooo, I already forgot my username and can't login anymore, because for some reason it shows a display name (?) why even have a user name then? And I can't reply because I need 'reputation' for that.
Anyhow, thanks for the attempt one that I also had tried already.

Comment: If 1113 is counted twice and it's an error , you must eliminate duplicated rows. You can use the embeded feature in excel 2010 ribbon.